# What's difference between selenium webdriver and code injection in e2e test?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

When we refers to E2E tests(end to end), there are many tools for us to begin.
I came into contact with some tools based on `selenium webdriver` not long ago, such as `wd.js`, `nightwatch.js` and `protractor`. All of these requires selenium server and can works well in e2e test.

And there is another way people do with e2e test is to **inject javascript** code into one page to run test, things may like this.

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var expect = require('expect.js');
var es = require('event-simulate');

describe('test button click', function () {
  it('should return right number', function (done) {
    var count = Number($('.countButton').eq(0).text());
    es.simulate($('.clickButton').eq(0),'click');
    setTimeout(function(){
      expect(Number($('.countButton').eq(0).text())).to.be(count+1);
      done();
    },500)
  });
});
```

Yeah, it uses some libraries like `jquery` to get selector and `event-simulate` to dispatch events.

And I want to know the differences between these two ways to run e2e tests, such as cons and pros to compare.

What I consider now is that the second way may lose browser compatibility, for example, some version of `ie` doesn't support for `mouseenter` stuff. And webdriver uses native api, it may get better compatibility tests. Any other parts to compare their cons and pros?